# DynamoDB provisioned Write Capacity Units exceeded too often and unexpectedly

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I believe I understand Write/Read capacity units, how they work and are calculated in DynamoDB. Proof of that is that I understand [this](https://linuxacademy.com/howtoguides/posts/show/topic/20310-how-to-calculate-read-and-write-capacity-for-dynamodb) article thoroughly as well as the [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughput.html#ProvisionedThroughput.CapacityUnits.Write). That said I'm experiencing an unexpected behavior when writing items to my table.

I have a DynamoDB table with the following settings. Most notably 5 Write/Read Capacity Units

[image: dynamodb table settings overview]

I'm putting in this table readings from sensors connected to a Raspberry Pi that I get and send with `python2.7` to Dynamo with [my script](https://gist.github.com/alejo4373/c5a11a8241337688f46bbf883c72fd79).

This items are less than 1KB for sure. They look like this:

```
{
    "reading_id": "<current_time>",
    "sensor_id": "<SENSORS_IDS[i]>",
    "humidity": "<humidity>",
    "temperature": "<temperature>"
}
```

[My script](https://gist.github.com/alejo4373/c5a11a8241337688f46bbf883c72fd79) iterates over the sensors, reads from one and submits the sensor's reading/item to DynamoDB with `table.put_item` every 5 seconds. That is, if the read from the sensors was successful otherwise arbitrarily wait 30s.

Now according to my calculations, I'm writing to DynamoDB 1KB item every 5 seconds, which should be fine since my table is setup up with 5WCU = (5items*1KB)/Second write throughput.

So my questions are:

**1**. How is it that this small load (if happens as I believe is happening) is exceeding my 5 WCU as seen here?:

[image: dynamodb table write capacity units metric]

**2**. I have been operating with this setup without changes for about a year(free tier ends September 30, 2018). How is it that, it began to change a few months ago even before the free tier ended, as seen here?:

[image: dynamodb billing ytd]

My only suspect so far is [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/time.html#time.sleep) since in the documentation, it says:

> time.sleep(secs)
>
> Suspend execution of the current thread for the given number of seconds. The argument may be a floating point number to indicate a more precise sleep time. The actual suspension time may be less than that requested because any caught signal will terminate the sleep() following execution of that signal’s catching routine. Also, the suspension time may be longer than requested by an arbitrary amount because of the scheduling of other activity in the system.

I am not very familiar with python which makes me think that it could be something in my code. That doesn't explain the fact that I was not having this issue earlier in the year though.

**Anyone** has any idea of the answers to the questions above or where should I investigate this issue further?

*Note:* I searched Google and other related questions here. None seemed to apply to my case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your table has been partitioned unevenly. You might want to read about [DynamoDB Partitions and Data Distribution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.Partitions.html).

Comment: So thanks to @mike-dinescu 's answer I discarded the possibility that my provisioned WCU is not enough. Your point is making sense since I have only 3 sensors and the sensorId is the Partion Key for the table. That means that my table is only partitioned in 3. But I think my requests are evenly distributed across the PKs since my write/read patterns are evenly distributed. I'm thinking what is said [here](https://amzn.to/2QngVuT): a partition should not exceed 1000WCU but [here](https://amzn.to/2LqhQbn) they said if the partition becomes full a new partition will be allocated. Still Confused

Comment: @AlejandroFranco - your table is not yet partitioned: at 200 MB and 5 WCU, it still operates with a single partition, so all 5 capacity units are allocated to the same partition that all your sensor data is actually being written to. Once you hit 10GB, the table will split in two, with approximately 3 WCU (2.5 routed up) in each partition.

Answer (score 0):

The graph you are sharing is showing consumption aggregated over a minute. That is, the sum of all capacity consumed over each 60 seconds, for each data point on the graph.

When you provision a table with 5 WCU then that means you can only write up to 5 1KB items *each* second. Effectively that gives you a total of up to 300 WCU that you could use in each minute.

So, as long as you see data points of 6 or so then that is totally fine.

One thing to notice is the *sum* of provisioned write throughput (the orange line) is actually not a sum. That seems to be a bug in CloudWatch: it is instead the per-second provisioned throughput.

A minor observation:  you are showing 5-6 units each minute, that means you are actually sleeping for closer to 10 seconds, not 5 between writes.

Lastly, with Dynamo you pay for the capacity that you reserve, not what you consume. So as long as your table is not being throttled, even when you go slightly over the provisioned capacity (which Dynamo allows in certain cases) you will not be charged extra.

Comment: Your answer definitely clarified the graphs for me. 5WCU are more than enough to handle my write rate as backed by [this more accurate graph](https://imgur.com/ofdRxup) found in the metrics tab of the table. Now I'm suspecting that the problem might be unevenly distribution of my data.

Comment: I'm sorry @AlejandroFranco but now I'm confused.  The graphs clearly show that your consumed capacity is miniscule. You're essentially *averaging* less than 1 W/second and your table is provisioned with 5 WCU, so it clearly has more capacity than you are using. What exactly is the problem that you are seeing?